# objective c: method returns an array of int

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I'm trying to to create a method that returns an array of int but I have some problems.

```
-(NSMutableArray *) PHSAPP:(float) tax
{
    ////code to calculate values


    if (Dlimloss50==0)  Dlimloss50=duration;

    if (Dlimloss95==0)  Dlimloss95=duration;

    if (DlimTre==0)   DlimTre=duration;

    NSLog(@"%d --- %d-----%d", Dlimloss50,Dlimloss95,DlimTre);

    NSNumber *uno=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Dlimloss50];
    NSNumber *due=[NSNumber numberWithInt:Dlimloss95];
    NSNumber *tre=[NSNumber numberWithInt:DlimTre];

    //// here values are changed    

    NSLog(@"%d --- %d-----%d", uno ,due ,tre);

    NSMutableArray *PHSAPP = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:3 ];

    [PHSAPP addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Dlimloss50]];
    [PHSAPP addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:Dlimloss95]];
    [PHSAPP addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:DlimTre]];

    return PHSAPP;
}
```

Values in the first NSLog are different from the values in the second NSLog and so the array is filled with wrong values.
Why?

Comment: you cant use %d with NSNumbers, use %@ instead

Answer (score 2):

You can not print NSNumber value with %d formatter. Use %@ instead.

Change

```
NSLog(@"%d --- %d-----%d", uno ,due ,tre);
```

to

```
NSLog(@"%@ --- %@-----%@", uno ,due ,tre);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the integer values:

```
NSNumber *uno = @10;
NSLog(@"%i", uno.intValue);
```